# Flurl API not sending POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net, flurl

I need to post webhook info into my database. That is simple enough and I can do that, but I'm having issues updating a line item that has already been inserted into the database. I figured I could change the post I have to a put, but that wouldn't add new entries. I tried to make a solution with this code.

```
var responseString7 = await url
            .GetAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(true);

        if (responseString7.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseString = await url
            .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .PutJsonAsync(new
            {
                trackingNumber = stuff.result.tracking_code,
                EPTrackingStatus = stuff.result.status,
                EPStatusDetails = stuff.result.status_detail,
                EPUpdatedAt = stuff.result.updated_at
            })
            .ReceiveString();
        }
        else
        {
            var responseString3 = await "url you cant see"
                .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .PostJsonAsync(new
                {
                    trackingNumber = stuff.result.tracking_code,
                    EPTrackingStatus = stuff.result.status,
                    EPStatusDetails = stuff.result.status_detail,
                    EPUpdatedAt = stuff.result.updated_at
                })
                .ReceiveString();
```

This solution will PUT but not POST. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean it "won't"? What exactly happens when you run it using POST? Do you get some sort of error response from the server, perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean by running it using POST? Do you mean if the else statement is ran? Or do you mean when I just used Put and it wouldn't create a new line item.

Comment: You said "This solution will PUT but not POST" ...so presumably there's an error when you try to POST? If Put is working then we don't need to focus on that. (P.S. whether Put adds a new line or not is up to the server. Convention in REST/CRUD style APIs is for POST to create a new entry, and PUT to update an entry, but that's just a convention. The server can do whatever it likes in reality)

Comment: Or maybe I just misunderstood you completely. At first you say you you're having issues updating an existing line item. Then you say "but it wouldn't add new entries".  But surely if you wanted to update, then not creating new entries is a good thing?? I don't know if it's just how you've worded the question, but you seem a bit confused about what you actually want to achieve, or where there's a problem. Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for helping me! To clarify the part where I said I was having issues updating line items, I was being stupid and mistyped so please ignore that part. Here is the problem worded as best as I can. My program is receiving webhook calls from multiple orders and I need to place the webhook information being sent to me into my database. The issue is that I can't make duplicate entries for orders that have the same ID so I must make separate post or put calls based on whether there is an entry already with that ID. For some reason, the code above only does put request.

Comment: so you mean it never enters the `else` block to attempt a POST? If so, I would expect that's because SuccessStatusCode is always true. I don't know what that URL GetAsync is supposed to return, but I would expect the HTTP status code to always be successful, even if the request returned no results. Returning no results doesn't indicate a technical failure of the actual request. You need to check the content of the response to know what the outcome was in terms of data returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Flurl behaves differently (by default) than HttpClient](https://flurl.dev/docs/error-handling/) with respect to errors. If it hits a non-2xx response, it throws. So it's not getting to your `else` block because an exception is thrown first. The easiest way to fix your code is to disable that behavior:

```
url.AllowAnyHttpStatus().GetAsync();
```

In the next call, if everything except the verb is the same in the 2 cases (URL, header, data), you might consider simplifying this a bit using Flurl's `SendJsonAsync`, where you specify the HTTP verb as a variable.

```
var method = getResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode ? HttpMethod.Put : HttpMethod.Post;

var responseString3 = await url
    .WithHeader(...)
    .SendJsonAsync(method, new { ... })
    .ReceiveString();
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe the .AllowAnyHttpStatus() fixed it, thank you!

Comment: Also, I'm not sure the second code part would work with my code. POST and PUT require different urls

Comment: Ah. Well, you could always add a `var url = getResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode ? ...`. Or not. Total judgement call, just feels like there might room for reducing code there.